# Android Facebook Open Graph request for type reference

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-opengraph

Can i pass `String array` with the request Parameter Bundle ?. Its not working for me.Any one suggest an alternative ? . I have to post a custom reference type value in that `array`. When using `putString()` it working fine. Tried with `action.setProperty()` method and still not working

Code

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putInt("data1", 1);
params.putStringArray("key",new String[]{arrayvalue"})

Request request = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(),
                    FacebookConstants.POST_ACTION_PATH_COMPLETE, params,
                    HttpMethod.POST);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the bundle (or the Request class) does not do any JSON encoding for individual parameter values.

If you want to pass in a string array, you need to JSON encode it yourself first into a String value, and set it as the "key" in the bundle.

Comment: thanks. Created a class that extends OpenGraphAction and set the propertise using @PropertyName() ; Working fine now.